# How can I create unique player combination for 7 round from 8 players

Tags: php, c++, c, algorithm

I have a problem and trying to develop or use an algorithm to solve this problem.

I have 8 players and each player can form 7 unique teams with other players. A team consist of 2 players.

Here is an example, 
Lets say all the players name are

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]
```

Now from this 8 players I can create total of `28` unique team combination.

Now I want to make 7 rounds and each round they must play with unique team.

I tried `round robin algorithm` but it works for 4 rounds. Not being able to create 7 rounds.

```
A B C D
E F G H 

ROUND 1: AE, BF, CG, DH 

E A B C
F G H D

ROUND 2: EF, AG, BH, CD 

F E A B 
G H D C 

ROUND 3: FG, EH, AD, BC, 

G F E A 
H D C B

ROUND 4: GH, FD, EC, AB
```

I still need to create 3 more rounds with unique set of players combination.

Any help would appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That was a fun problem :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep maximum diversity, each player should never be paired with a player they have previously paired with. Since there are 8 players and 7 rounds, this means each player will need to match up with each other player exactly once. There are 4 pairs per round.

Since there are 8 players, we can represent each individual player as a bit in a byte.

```
Enum PlayerId : Byte {
    PLAYER_A = 1,
    PLAYER_B = 2,
    PLAYER_C = 4,
    PLAYER_D = 8,
    PLAYER_E = 16,
    PLAYER_F = 32,
    PLAYER_G = 64,
    PLAYER_H = 128
}

// player index to player id lookup
PlayerId _playerIds[] = { PLAYER_A, PLAYER_B, PLAYER_C, ... }
```

For each individual player there are 7 unique pairings, all of which will be seen in a game. For each round we need 4 such pairings without conflict: ie, all players must  exactly once throughout all such pairings.

We'll use a graph to represent all the possibilities. We'll create a node for each possible pairing, and we'll create edges between nodes that are compatible with one another (ie, no conflict in player selections).

```
public class PairingGraph {
    Map<Byte, PairingNode*> nodes = new Map<Byte, PairingNode*>();        
    Map<Byte, PairingEdge*> edges = new Map<Byte, PairingEdge*>();

    PairingNode* AddPairing(Player p1, Player p2) {
        PairingNode n(this, p1, p2);

        if(nodes.ContainsKey(n->id)) {
            throw new Exception("Duplicate Player Pairing");

        nodes[n->id] = n;

        for other : nodes {
            if(n->id & other->id) continue;                
            edges->Add(new PairingEdge(this, n, other)); 
        }

        return n;
    }

    boolean RemoveNode(Byte id) {
        if (!nodes.ContainsKey(id)) return false;

        auto n = nodes[id];

        // first remove any edges that this node is part of.
        for e : n->edges {
            if (e->p1 != n) {
                e->p1->edges.remove(e);
            } else {
                e->p2->edges.remove(e);
            }

            delete e;
        }

        nodes.remove(n);
        delete n;
        return true;
    }

    PairingGraph() {
        // initialize the graph with all player combinations
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < 8; j++) {
                AddPairing(_playerIds[i], _playerIds[j]);
            }
        }            
    }
}

public class PairingNode {
    PairingGraph* graph;
    List<PairingEdge> edges;
    PlayerId p1;
    PlayerId p2;
    Byte id;

    PairingNode(PairingGraph* g, PlayerId p1, PlayerId p2) {
        if(p1 == p2) throw new Exception("Two distinct players are required to create a PairingNode");
        this.graph = g;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.id = p1 | p2;
    }
}

public class PairingEdge {
    PairingGraph* g;
    PairingNode* p1;
    PairingNode* p2;
    Byte id;

    PairingEdge(PairingGraph* g, PairingNode* p1, PairingNode* p2) {
        if(p1->id & p2->id) throw new Exception("Cannot create edges between PairingNode's that share a player");
        this.graph = g;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.id = p1->id | p2->id;

        this.p1.edges.Add(this);
        this.p2.edges.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Now that we can construct a PairingGraph with all possible combinations, our algorithm for creating pairings is simple: Randomly select and remove nodes from the graph, with the additional constraint that a removed node not conflict with any previously selected nodes for the round.

```
List<Tuple<PlayerId, PlayerId>>* SelectPlayersForRound(PairingGraph* g) {

    List<Tuple<PlayerId, PlayerId>> results = new List<Tuple<PlayerId, PlayerId>>;
    Byte restrictions = 0;

    // start by randomly selecting an intial node.
    int selection = rand(0, g->nodes->count -1);
    auto last_node = g->nodes[g->nodes->keys(selection)];
    restrictions |= n->id;
    selectedNodes.Add(n);

    // select the three other player pairs, informed from previous selections.
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {            
        // start by randomly selecting an edge from the last node
        // it necessarily won't conflict with the last_node, but may
        // not meet all restriction criteria
        int selection = rand(0, last_node->edges->count -1);

        // Grab the node on the opposite end of the selected edge
        auto e = last_node->edges[selection];
        auto next_node = (e->p1 == last_node)? e->p2 : e->p1;

        // If the node doesn't meet our current restrictions, try again.
        while(next_node->id & restrictions) {
            selection++;
            if(selection == last_node->edges->count) selection++;
            e = last_node->edges[selection];
            next_node = (e->p1 == last_node)? e->p2 : e->p1;
        }

        // Remove the last_node from the Graph
        g->RemoveNode(last_node->id);

        // update for next iteration
        last_node = curr_node;
        restrictions |= last_node->id;
    }

    // Remove the last_node from the Graph
    g->RemoveNode(last_node->id);

    return results;
}
```

Just create a new PairingGraph for each game, and call SelectPlayersForRound each round and you are done!

Please note that this is just some psuedo-code (since you didn't specify a language) and it has not been tested. Hope it helps :)

EDIT: You have added some languages to the post. My psuedo-code is more or less c++ so you should be able to copy-modify for your purposes easily.

EDIT2: Improved the selection routine to make use of the last_node's list of compatible edges (reducing the # of potential conflicts)

EDIT3: Fixed some of the conditional logic where I was improperly using ^ instead of &

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please write a simple algorithm of it? Didn't understand your psuedo-code fully..

Comment: I'd be happy to clarify, just let me know what parts you are having troubles with.